# Long to Float Conversion in Android

Tags: java, android

How to covert a `Long` value to `Float` in Android?

Float

```
amt=NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse(products.get(i).getAmount().substring(0,products.get(i).getAmount().length() - 3));
```

This code arises the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity and readability's sake, first get the `NumberFormat`, then cast the parsed `Number` to a float with `floatValue()`.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
String amount = products.get(i).getAmount();
Number number = numberFormat.parse(amount.substring(0,amount.length() - 3));
Float amt = number.floatValue();
```

Comment: Why use a `Long` when a `Number` will do? For all you know, the `Number` returned may not be of type `Long` at some point in the future, which would lead you to the same `ClassCastException`. You can call `longValue()` on any `Number` (but you could just as easily call `floatValue()`and forego the cast, as I did in my answer). You still got my upvote :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right in this instance. I'm just trying to provide an answer that someone in the future, besides the OP, will be able to use to convert a Long to a Float as was asked in the question. I'm going to revenge upvote you for your more thought out answer.

Comment: That doesn't even compile, since [`NumberFormat.parse(String source)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat#parse(java.lang.String)) returns a `Number`, not a `Long`.

Comment: I had edited it almost immediately but my internet shut off and it was a bad time.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`floatValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#floatValue()) to get a `float` representation of your `Long` (or any `Number` for that matter). Then you can use the constructor `Float(float)`to create a `Float` object. This has the advantage of not relying on the `Number` returned by your code to be a `Long`.

```
Number amt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse(products.get(i).getAmount().substring(0,products.get(i).getAmount().length() - 3));
Float amtFloat = new Float(amt.floatValue());
```

Comment: No need for `new Float()`. Auto-boxing will take care of that for you.

Comment: @Andreas True. And I guess since Java 5 came out ages ago, I might as well start relying on it. But I consider it no harm done to box manually when providing an answer on SO – after all, someone reading the question might be using an outdated version of Java.